# Optimal Manipulation of Long Bitwise Structures

Tags: c++, c, optimization, bit-manipulation

So I am working on a project that needs to be absolutely efficient in terms of memory and runtime, and I've come up with a way to represent part of the problem by hundreds of 'sets' of Boolean switches (like 0101000100...), that reach lengths on the order of 20,000.  I think I know from how a processor works that bitwise operations can manipulate entire regions of memory in O(1) time (or maybe just one CPU instruction), as bits literally flow through logic gates in parallel.  I've considered using `std::bitset`, but I have decided that it's not a compact enough structure, and when doing bitwise operations it does search over the entire bitset in some kind of 'foreach' loop.

I want to manipulate 1's and 0's in memory.  The best way I have thought of doing this is stringing together a bunch of meaningless uint64_t types (perhaps in an array) and, very much like a `std::bitset`, search over all uint64_t and do bitwise operations against another 20,000-long set of switches.  I am well aware that this is not an O(1) operation, and I am essentially doing the same thing algorithmically as `std::bitset` or even `std::vector<bool>` and `std::array<bool, 20000>`, etc.  But the extra compactness of using uint64_t results in speed and memory differences significant enough to affect my program's runtime and space-complexity within our sample spaces, even if we are in the same time complexity as the standard library operations.  My question is, is this the optimal way to carry out operations over a 20,000-long set of switches?  Is there a way to do bitwise operations on 20,000 bit-long regions of memory in O(1) time, or an O(n) method that is better than mine?  I supremely doubt it, but if this is possible it would quite literally solve a huge challenge that has plagued our project.

**DEMONSTRATION**: We are trying to see if this O(n) operation can be performed in O(1) by doing bitwise AND over the entire switch structure instead of plugging 64-bit chunks one at a time.  Each individual bitwise AND here is an O(1) operation by the CPU instruction on a 64-bit processor, I presume, but can I somehow do 20,000-long bitwise AND?

```
uint64_t switch1[313]; //20,032 meaningful switches e.g. 100...101
uint64_t switch2[313]; //20,032 meaningful switches e.g. 110...010

uint64_t result[313]; //result of 20,032-long bitwise AND
for (int i = 0; i < 313; ++i) {
    result[i] = switch1[i] & switch2[i];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is processor specific and compiler specific. You could use GPGPUs with [OpenCL](https://opencl.org/).... I am not sure that bit by bit operations are always faster than byte ones (e.g. `bool`). You should benchmark

Comment: See also [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/), and consider meta programming techniques, partial evaluation, generation of specialized machine code at runtime using [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) or [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/)

Comment: Please show some C code or C++ code (i.e. some [mre]) Be aware that C and C++ are very different programming language.

Comment: Thank you very much @BasileStarynkevitch.  We are noting all of the options there are, and GPU computing is a next step for our lab.

Comment: "We are trying to make this O(n) operation into an O(1) operation." I guess that is theoretically impossible or related to the [P vs NP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). See  [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem)

Comment: On x86 processors, a good search term is `vectorize`. Good tags to search are `[simd]` and/or `[avx]`, `[avx2]`, `[avx512]`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I've revised the language since then.

Comment: @user3386109 This seems to be extremely related to what I need.  But why does it have to be x86?  I have an arm64 processor myself, for example.  I also see that taking advantage of this requires multiple cores, which makes sense to speed things up, but we are trying to optimize single-core performance first!

Comment: There's a structure called Binary Decision Diagram which can help in manipulating binary functions.

Comment: I think I am realizing that what I had initially thought is true.  This could only be O(1) if we have 20,000-bit processors.  But right now I'm stuck with a 64-bit processor.

Comment: @AndrewHowe it doesn't have to be x86, but it must be [tag:simd] and [tag:vectorization] because all modern architectures have [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) unit that can do bitwise operations on hundreds or thousands of bits in a single instruction, for example ARM has Neon/SVE and PPC has Altivec. The bitness of the architecture isn't important, you only need to care about the SIMD unit. This can further be optimized with multithreading and/or GPU off-loading

Comment: Even on a 1 million bit processor this would still be O(n). Because you are talking about the behavior as n goes to infinity. Even doing this one bit at a time is O(n) and there is no way around it being O(n). Anyway, you don't seem to be looking for efficiency but for performance. You want it to take less time for a fixed n.

Comment: Using SIMD, which the compiler should do automatically if you write sensible code, will speed this up a bit. But you really should consider a change of algorithm so you don't need to manage 20000 bit bitfields. For that you have to say a lot more about what you are doing with those bitfields.

Comment: See example on how the compiler auto-vectorize your code https://godbolt.org/z/Kodx49fcj but the concern about algorithm is real, because otherwise the question will become [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Okay, I guess I'm not being precise enough with my language.  It will always be an O(n) operation then.  But in terms of performance, the way the CPU parallelizes n-bit operations makes it behave like an n-long bitwise AND is executed in O(1) time.  This may be a wrong interpretation too.  I appreciate your enquiry as well, but a long bitfield is the irreducible data we are working with to represent regulator-target edges in a transcription network.  I work in a computational biology lab.  It may not be worth it to explain the problem more.

Comment: `std:bitset` is just a blob of memory and provides the bitwise operations. Where exactly so you see any overhead?